# How do I list all files with their size and last modified date?

Tags: linux, bash, find

I would like to list all files in human readable format size and date stamp including files in sub-directories and sort it all by size. Currently I can do that with the code below:

```
find /sasdata/ -name "*.sas7bdat" -exec ls -lthS  {} + | sort -r -h | awk '{print $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10,$11,$12,$13}' >> sasdata_all.txt &
```

It is sorted by size and not per folder. I want it to sort all the files regardless of its path. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about :

```
find . -printf '%s %p\n' | sort -h -r | head
```

which in my case outputs :

```
120050424 ./go1.13.linux-amd64.tar.gz
25831312 ./Projects/Practica_SDL/include/Game.h.gch
25040336 ./Projects/Practica_SDL/include/Letter.h.gch
24216593 ./go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/compile
16867656 ./journey-linux-amd64/journey
15075523 ./go/bin/go
14821094 ./go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/pprof
```

File sizes are in bytes.